# Не могу установить модули. Python 3.5 or later required

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь установить пару модулей (Numpy и Arcade) при попытке выдает следующую ошибку:

> Python 3.5 or later required

Стоит питон версии 3.4 и есть второй 3.4.4 с такой же проблемой. Выше поставить нет возможности, стоит Windows XP 32.
   Строка запущена от админа, разумеется
[image: Командная строка]
[image: Полное избражение]

Comment: У вас есть какой-то вопрос? Причина проблемы ясно изложена, как решать - очевидно. Если нет возможности поставить 3.5 или выше, значит придется как-то обходиться без этих модулей. Ну или найти более старые версии, которые не требуют 3.5.

Comment: Ну значит модуль (конкретно whl файл) не поддерживает Python ниже 3.5. Проще всего решить проблему скачав собранный модуль конкретно для Python 3.4, например, [отсюда](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) (модуль для версии 3.4 - тот что содержит cp34 в имени).

Comment: Вот поэтому лучше сразу что-то типа Anaconda ставить, чтобы она за зависимостями следила и сама ставила совместимые между собой пакеты. Хотя у неё свои приколы.

Comment: Я бы поставил Анаконду3, и пытался, но она в конце установки при создании меню выдает ошибку.
Видимо под ХР не вариант поставить какой то рабочий вариант

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pip install numpy==1.16.6
```

Подходящую версию Arcade ищите тут https://pypi.org/project/arcade/2.2.3/#history

Comment: Попробовал установить эту версию, ошибка осталась той же(

Comment: Выложите полный текст ошибки в исходном вопросе. От момента команды до конца. желательно текстом.

Comment: Что именно не поставилось? Ничего или Arcade?

Comment: Ничего, ни numpy ни arcad
я уже понял, что версии не совместимы с 3.4 и требуют минимум 3.5, что не возможно, так как стоит ХР.

Comment: Можно поставить старую версию. Согласно документации pip numpy 1.16.6 должна подходить. Если не подходит, ставьте более раннюю. Идите в раздел https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.16.6/#history и там подберите нужную. А при установке явно задайте версию. Как именно - я написал в ответе.

Comment: Перед установкой рекомендую:
python -m pip install --upgrade pip и
pip install -U setuptools

Comment: Поставил оба модуля, после множества проб и ошибок.

Comment: На python 3.4 встала версия numpy-1.15.0 и arcade - 1.0.0